# Why does pip install raise a SyntaxError?

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install Flask but I get a syntax error when I use `pip install`.  How do I use pip to install Flask?

```
>>> pip install Flask
  File "<stdin>", line 1
   pip install Flask
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You run pip from the command line, not the python interpreter.

Answer (score 3):

`pip` is a command line tool not a python command. You need to run it on the command line, not in python.

P.S. When you see an example that starts a line with `$` it generally means something that should be run from the command line, if it's meant to be run in python it will start with `>>>`.

Comment: @Michtel @CrazyCasta There is built-in pip module, but it has to be imported first as other modules. Usage: `pip.main(['install', 'package', '--upgrade'])`

Comment: @Zydnar Ok, I technically stand corrected. However, Mitchel already knows how to do stuff from the command line, so why try to teach him something new? Also in certain cases you'll have to restart python anyway to fix get things settled. For something like this, just run it from the command line.

Comment: Correct, but OP question look like, he asked about using pip in python shell. I am not assuming he done it by accident. Some packages programmers install before they start programming... `print 'foo'` in python 2.x is correct expression so `pip install flask` looks like simple misunderstanding of syntax. Or am I thinking too much... :)

Comment: You're thinking too much because his syntax is exactly correct for use from the command line. It would be like telling someone to use `import sys; print sys.path` when they tried to use `echo $PATH`. Likely they just want to be told that `echo $PATH` should be run from the command line, not the python interpreter.